# How to render external file/component into my React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, render, external

I want to know how can I render external file/component into my react js app?

I have this file name file.jsx it contain some code:

```
import React from "react";

 const TestingFile = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            Hello world!
        </div>
    )
 }
 export default TestingFile;
```

and it is outside my react app. I want it to be render without import stuff...my issue here is that I don't know how to do it, or is it possible to this kind of rendering?
And this is my React app code:

```
import  React from "react";
function App() {

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
     <TestingFile />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

note: My React app and file.jsx stand on different directory!!!

Be able to output or rendering external file/component to the browser interface.

Comment: The app file isn't importing the `TestingFile` component.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Exactly, my issue here how can I render this component without moving the file into src or without importing? This file.jsx is outside the project app and how I can render?

Comment: I don't think you can. Unless `TestingFile` is globally available?